# No package kernel-devel-3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64 available

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

```
[root@localhost ~]# uname -a
   Linux localhost.localdomain 3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Nov 8 23:39:32 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[root@bogon ~]# yum install -y "kernel-devel-$(uname -r)"
   error: No package kernel-devel-3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64 available
```

*I run it in centos7.6, after i run cmd `yum update kernel`,it workes ok. Can i fix it without update kernel?*

Comment: I have that exact same problem.
`yum -y install kernel-devel` gives me `kernel-devel-3.10.0-1062.1.2.el7.x86_64` even though I want `3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64`.

Comment: ... and `/lib/modules/3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64/build` is a link to `/usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64` which does not exist as I just have `/usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-1062.1.2.el7.x86_64/`.

Comment: `kernel-3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64` → Old package(s) → **vault.centos**  → http://vault.centos.org/7.6.1810/os/x86_64/Packages/kernel-3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64.rpm ... ← ref. http://vault.centos.org/7.6.1810/os/x86_64/Packages/